# snmpwalk on mac OSX not returning all values when grepping

Tags: macos, grep, snmp

I am using snmpwalk on my mac to gather information about a copier. When I run a query for a specific OID, it returns its value correctly:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -On 10.x.x.x 1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.8.1.20.101

output: 1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.8.1.20.101 = STRING: "Black Single Impressions"
```

however, when I walk the mib and grep, it does not return this value:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -On 10.x.x.x | grep -i 'Black'

output:
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.1 = STRING: "Black Toner, PN unknown;SN4131EE80E00004A8"
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.4 = STRING: "black"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.1 = STRING: "1-sided paper path, Black/White (45) PPM, Color (45) PPM"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.2 = STRING: "2-sided long edge feed paper path, Black/White (45) PPM, Color (45) PPM"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.3 = STRING: "2-sided paper path, Black/White (32) PPM, Color (32) PPM"
```

when I grep for the OID of 'Black Single Impressions' it also returns nothing:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -On 10.x.x.x | grep 1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.8.1.20.101
```

why isnt snmpwalk returning everything on a walk? this is kind of important for researching what values equal what, I got lucky finding my example.

Comment: Your two `snmpwalk` commands are different. Your first step is to compare those without the added complication of a `grep`. If they don't match, that may be a SNMP agent bug or misconfiguration and now you have an entirely different question requiring more context and information.

Comment: Also look at the `snmpwalk` manpage under `-Cc` - some agents are _known_ to be buggy in the way they walk the MIB, in a way that could cause `snmpwalk` to error out by default (i.e. while it's in what I'll call "strict mode"). If so, you masked the error message with the `grep`. Again, your first step is to _break the problem down into little pieces_ and only change one thing at a time.

Comment: Anyway let me know how you get on and I'll be happy to come back to this as I like SNMP questions.

Comment: BTW usually to get a single scalar you'd invoke `snmpget`, not `snmpwalk`. You're wasting traffic by requiring a _GetNext_ to begin walking an apparently non-existent subtree, before Net-SNMP does its final _Get_ on the requested OID.